# WebStorm thinks Error constructor has zero args

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, constructor, webstorm

Running WebStorm 2019.1 with ECMAScript 6 language level.

If I do the following:

```
new Error('Foobar');
```

it will not produce any warnings. But if I do the following:

```
class SomeError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
  }      
}
```

Then WebStorm complains on the call to the super constructor, saying *Invalid number of arguments, expected 0*.

I also tried using spread arguments, such as

```
constructor(...args) {
  super(...args);
}
```

This gives the same results - *0 args expected*.

Checking the `lib.es5.d.ts` file, the interfaces for Error look like this:

```
interface Error {
   name: string;
   message: string;
   stack?: string;
}

interface ErrorConstructor {
   new(message?: string): Error;
   (message?: string): Error;
   readonly prototype: Error;
}

declare var Error: ErrorConstructor;
```

This looks correct to me. So why does the IDE insist that when extending `Error`, the super-class constructor must not have any arguments? Sure, I can do `this.message = message;` instead, but I'm curious as to what's going on.
Is this a problem with the IDE, with some of my settings for language level compatibility, or am I stupid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known issue, [WEB-32758](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32758) is fixed in upcoming IDEA 2019.2